# Where do people say "on Christmas"?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english

Normally, English native speakers use *on*  and *at* with the festive holiday in the following manner

1. We open our gifts **on** Christmas morning.
2. We're going away **at** Christmas

The preposition *on* is used for dates, days of the week, and names of public holidays
  e.g., Many florists make a profit *on* Valentine's day

But if a holiday covers a period of two or more days then the preposition *at* is used

3. Children often hope for snow **at** Christmas
4. We always stuff ourselves with chocolate **at** Easter

Recently, I discovered that  in some parts of the US this is not always the case

> While “on Christmas day” is hardly unusual, I would say that just “on Christmas” is the more frequently-heard expression, by a considerable margin. Might be a cultural thing, though (my experience is the American Northeast for the most part)

and in an old EL&U [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/44836/44619) this phrase was submitted

> We got together **on Christmas** for dinner and a gift exchange.

I also found supporting  [reference](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm)

> *Note that in some varieties of English people say "on the weekend" and "on Christmas".

- Where do native English speakers omit *Day/day* and instead say **on Christmas**?
- Does *on Christmas* refer to 25th December, or is it also used to cover the entire  holiday season?

This question is related, and inspired by the ELL question:
[What is the difference between 'at Christmas' and 'on Christmas'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/109946/what-is-the-difference-between-at-christmas-and-on-christmas)

Comment: @JOSH well, I wouldn't  say "I went to the cinema on Christmas" but "... on Christmas Day" And why was  the footnote included in the link I posted? It's not "standard" in my speech.

Comment: "... on Xmas Day" or "I'm visiting friends and relatives at Christmas." Just saying:  "I'm going to be out on Christmas" sounds ambiguous to me, is it 25th December or the holiday period? EDIT: Well, it's a pity JOSH deleted their comments.

Comment: ***All alone on Christmas*** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Alone_on_Christmas

Comment: *Welcome back*.

Comment: Why do I think that the expression "on Christmas" instead of the normal "at Christmas" is used mainly by the Irish? Just my experience, I guess, but you'll often hear them use expressions like "Ed's not here; he's on lunch", when everyone else says "he's at lunch".

Comment: "At Christmas" and "at the weekend" are not generally used in AmE. We'd likely use "for". I'm going home for Christmas.

Comment: I don't think there's any hard-and-fast "rule" for this in AmE.  "On", "at", "for", and likely a few others are all used, depending on the context, and the speaker's preference.  Most listeners would not notice a switch between the words, except in specific cases.  The main difference is that "on" implies the specific day, while the other terms might refer to the "season".

Comment: GloWbE has 5686 instances of "on Christmas" , but if you remove cases with 'day', 'Eve', 'morning', or 'night', there are only 1176. A further load are "on Christmas Island/gifts/trees etc". If I focus on "On Christmas" followed by 'or', 'and' or punctuation, it's about 400, of which about a third are US.

Comment: “At Christmas” sounds quite distinctly odd to me. I would definitely say that children hope for snow _for_ Christmas, or _over_ Christmas… or even _on_ Christmas (though I agree that sounds more American). “At Easter” sounds even stranger to my ear, though “on Easter” is no better. “Over Easter” is the only one that doesn’t sound strange to me there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet there are a large number of examples for [**wished "for snow" "at Christmas"**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=wished+%22for+snow%22+%22at+Christmas%22), which I Googled up for you :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I didn't say people don't say it, just that it sounds odd to me. People say lots of things that sound odd to me. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Remember, when you point your finger there are three others pointing back at you.  (Unless you're a cartoon character, in which case there are only two..)

Comment: My thought is that much like "day" is being omitted when saying "on Christmas", that "time" is being omitted when saying "at Christmas". So the full saying in your second example would be "We're going away at Christmas *time*". /thought

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm an American, and I always use 'on' with a holiday, never 'at'. I've lived in different parts of the US and Canada, and I can't recall hearing a North American say 'at Christmas'. My impression is that this is very much a cultural difference in usage.

It seems to me that we only add 'day' if we want to clarify that we're referring specifically to December 25th, but often temporal context makes it clear enough that we don't need to specify. For example, if I ask someone who lives abroad whether they're going home for Christmas, they'll know I mean the holiday period and not just the day, since almost no one would travel internationally for a single day's visit. If my friend lives in the same town as her parents and I ask her whether she's going to her parents' house for Christmas, she will know I mean the day, since it's unlikely that someone would spend a week with their parents when they have their own home nearby.

Comment: An American might say "at Christmastime"

Answer (score 3):

This is something we're explicitly made aware of when teaching English to foreign students as we teach British English but need to be aware of American English so that they don't become confused and unsure of what is correct when they hear American English used.

Traditionally in British English, "at" is always used for festivities. "At Christmas", "At Easter", whereas "on" is always used for days and dates in both British and American English. Thus "On Christmas day" is considered correct in both British and American English.

Using "On Christmas" is a uniquely North American phenomena, regardless of whether the speaker is simply abbreviating the phrase "Christmas day" or referring to the entire festival season. It's rare to hear someone say "on Christmas" in the British Isles, the only exception being foreigners with American influenced English.

In North America the phrase "On Christmas" is often used to refer to both the festival season and to the specific day itself, and generally context is used to distinguish whether the speaker is referring to the day or to the whole season.

I will add, however, that I believe "at Christmas" is not unheard of in North America, and that while it may have lost ground to "on Christmas", "at Christmas" can still be heard in various regions. I also believe that you'll frequently find "at Christmas" in older American literature as "on Christmas" as only become accepted as correct in American English relatively recently.

It might be worth nothing that a lot of preposition are possible with "Christmas", for, over, during, they all work as well, and various dialects have slight differences in preference when it comes to which to use when.

Comment: As a native speaker of American English I can say I never use *on Christmas* to refer to "the festival season." Rather, I use *over Christmas*,  *for Christmas*, or multiple words (*Christmas break*, *Christmas season*, *Christmas vacation*, etc), depending on context.

Comment: Just as _on Christmas_ is short for _on Christmas day_, the phrase _at Christmas_ is short for _during the Christmas holiday_. _For Christmas_ can either mean the same thing (_We're going to Tucson for/at Christmas this year_), or it can refer to gift exchange or other festive parts (_We're [giving the kids embroidered napkins/roasting a goose] for Christmas this year_).

Comment: @JohnLawler The only real distinction I am picking up here is that in America the name of 25th Dec is sometimes referred to simply as *Christmas*, whilst in Britain we would always say *Christmas Day* - (and use *on*). Part of the reason for this may be that for some Americans Christmas consists only of the 25th, whilst in Britain, as one American ex-pat. put it to me, "Christmas in the UK seems like 4th July, GW's birthday, Thanksgiving, and American Christmas all rolled into one." For many in Britain it is a ten-day holiday (for some a ten-day booze up!).